# Windows Form 2 minimizes on the closing of Form 1

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

Strange problem here. I have a Login form, which opens a Registration form when the user clicks a button:

```
Register registration = new Register();
registration.Show();
```

At which point, this second form opens in front of the Login form - both windows are open and not minimized, which is fine. However, when the user completes registration and the registration is successful:

```
if (success)
{
    this.Close(); //('this' being the Registration form)
}
```

The registration form closes (good), but then the Login form minimizes and I'm not sure why. Ideally I'd like the form to stay open the entire time rather than have to click the taskbar icon to display it on-screen again.

I imagine there's more to it than the code I supplied so happy to provide more if needed. Just not sure where the issue would lie.

Comment: Does the same happen with `ShowDialog`? Might be the better choice anyway.

Comment: Hey, that fixed it! Thanks marsze. I can't mark comments as answers, can I? Not sure of the protocol here, since your solution worked.

Comment: It's not actually an answer, but since it solved your problem in a way, I made it one.

Comment: Good stuff, I'll mark it as such as soon as Stack Overflow allows me to.

Comment: Crystal ball says that it did not minimize but disappeared behind the window of another application.  Typically Visual Studio's.  Happens when you tinker with the Enabled property and don't set it back to *true* soon enough.

Comment: Crystal ball would be wrong I'm afraid. It did minimize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I don't know why this happens (it shouldn't), `ShowDialog()` should be the better option here anyway.

Comment: It's an odd one, all right. Nevertheless, ShowDialog() works!

Answer (score 1):

I've now had the same problem, which even occured when using `ShowDialog()`. I did some research and after taking quite some time figuring out what it was, I found that setting `FormBorderStyle` to `System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow` (or `SizableToolWindow`) in the main form makes this happen. I also experienced (and can reproduce) a similar issue where even the child form can get minimized if it has `FixedToolWindow` set, so the only "real" solution for me is to not use this borderstyle on any form.

Changing this to any other `FormBorderStyle` value gets rid of this issue completely, although then you obviously cannot use this borderstyle anymore.

Leaving this answer here in hopes to help other people who stumble upon this very same problem, as it apparently still exists in 2019.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try showDialog(this)